# Jasmine unit testing: How to access property set by @input() ? Accessing it using component.propertyname returns undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

ts file:

```js
@input() selectedDep: WebMessagingDeployments[]
```

spec file:

```js
beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeploymentAssignmentFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
    console.log(component.selectedDep) // returns undefined
    component.selectedDep.push(mockDepData); //this line throws error. TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not initialized `selectedDep` in your component nor your test file.

A couple options are:

1. Initialize at declaration

   @Input() selectedDep: WebMessagingDeployments[] = [];
2. Initialize in test

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeploymentAssignmentFormComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   component.selectedDep = [/* value here */];
   fixture.detectChanges();